# javascript input value no update after manual input

Tags: javascript, input

If I enter something into t1, t2 is changed.
But if t2 already has manual input, it is not changed any more (and vice versa).

How can I change an input field that has already an manual input with javascript (without reloading the page!)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

inputfields are not changed, if they have/had an input already!<br />
<br />
t1: <input type="text" id="t1" value="" onchange="upd1()"><br /><br />
t2: <input type="text" id="t2" value="" onchange="upd2()">

<script>
function upd1() {
  t2.setAttribute("value", "changed");
  return true;
}

function upd2() {
  t1.setAttribute("value", "changed");
  return true;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm puzzled as to how that code even works without declaring and assigning values to `t1` or `t2`. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

You can also save an old value of each field to continue editing. Also it will show editing status on another field each time. It will be more comfortable for users.

```html
inputfields are not changed, if they have/had an input already!<br />
<br />
<input type="text" id="t1" value="" onClick="renderFirstEl()" onInput="upd1()"><br /><br />
<input type="text" id="t2" value="" onClick="renderSecondEl()" onInput="upd2()">

<script>
    let firstElValue = '';
    let secondElValue = '';

    function upd1() {
        let el = document.querySelector('#t2');
            el.value = 'changed';

        return true;
    }

    function upd2() {
        let el = document.querySelector('#t1');
            el.value = 'changed';

        return true;
    }
    
    function renderFirstEl() {
        let el = document.querySelector('#t1');

        secondElValue = document.querySelector('#t2').value;
        el.value = firstElValue;
    }
    
    function renderSecondEl() {
        let el = document.querySelector('#t2');

        firstElValue = document.querySelector('#t1').value;
        el.value = secondElValue;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is use this:

```js
function upd1() {
  t2.value = 'changed';
  return true;
}

function upd2() {
  t1.value = 'changed';
  return true;
}
```

```html
t1: <input type="text" id="t1" value="" onchange="upd1()"><br /><br />
t2: <input type="text" id="t2" value="" onchange="upd2()">
```

---

Value changes after you type in one of the inputs and press Enter.

Because as said here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp .

---

*"The setAttribute() method adds the specified attribute to an element, and gives it the specified value.
**If the specified attribute already exists, only the value is set/changed**."*